Cross-lingual re-ranking of the primary query results
I am working on an AI semantic/multilingual search engine using vector embeddings and Qdrant as my vector database. I included the full details of this process in this question which you can check out. I also posted my final solution in that question.
To go over the main topics:

I first generate weighted combined vectors for my products, and then query them using qdrant engine.
I then send the initial results to a re-ranker function which works as below:

from FlagEmbedding import FlagReranker
cross_encoder = FlagReranker("BAAI/bge-reranker-v2-m3", use_fp16=True)
def rerank_results(primary_results: list, search_query: str):
    """
    Reranks the primary search results based on cross-encoder scores obtained by comparing the search query with each result's title.

    Args:
    - primary_results (list): A list of primary search results, retrieved from search.search_query function using qdrant search.
    - search_query (str): The search query used for comparing and reranking the results.

    Returns:
    - list: The reranked search results ordered by the cross-encoder scores in descending order.
    """
    cross_inp = [[search_query, hit["title"]] for hit in primary_results[:72]]
    cross_scores = cross_encoder.compute_score(cross_inp, normalize=True)

    # Sort results by the cross-encoder scores
    for idx in range(len(cross_scores)):
        primary_results[idx]["cross-score"] = cross_scores[idx]
    hits = sorted(primary_results, key=lambda x: x.get("cross-score", 0), reverse=True)
    for hit in hits:
        print("hits:", hit["title"], hit.get("cross-score", 0))
    return hits


Then the results are much more better and related to the query.

However, the problem occurs when I try to perform cross-lingual searches. One of the main missions of this search engine is to perform these kind of queries using BAAI/bge-m3 model which supports over 100 languages and can semantically search in other languages. But, as I understand, re-ranker models mainly work on a token-based procedure, which means they perform a similarity check using tokens between the query and the hit title pair. Although my results are just fine for one language, using re-ranker completely destroys the cross-lingual ability of my engine.
I am looking for a re-ranking technique that can handle cross-lingual re-ranking. An example for this is, I want a re-ranker that can understand that "mavi gomlek erkek uchun" is as the same as "blue men's shirt". Although the first is in Turkish, and the second is in english. Is there any model or other techniques that I can use?
